# Remove space or blank line at begin

Tags: php

How to remove space or blank line at begin , i have on my site part where users can write description about self, but when u type 10 times space button you can save this in database.. how can i protect to type space at begin or remove ?

example:

```
                       with space
```

and

```
without space (this is good)
```

This is my code now:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET description='".addslashes(str_replace("\r\n"," ",$_POST[description]))."'";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
trim($_POST[description])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what `trim()` does:

```
$description = trim($_POST['description']);
```

If you only want the left or right side, use `rtrim()` or `ltrim()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

> string `trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )`
>
> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> ```
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To specifically remove from beginning, use

```
ltrim()
```

which removes whitespace from the left

Comment: Mind that it also removed whitespaces from the right: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Not the ltrim() function. Onlu the trim() function does.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notive the ltrim!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '              a string!';
$string = ltrim($string);
echo $string; //outputs 'a string!';
```

That said, you should really not be injecting user input directly in to your database. Please look at parameterized query or the like. adslashes is not good security.

Edit: ltrim() trims from the left, rtrim() trims from the right, and trim() trims both.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function ltrim if you want to remove the spaces from the beginning.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET description='".addslashes (ltrim(str_replace("\r\n"," ",$_POST[description])))."'";
```

And if you want to remove the spaces from both the beginning and the end, you can use the function trim.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET description='".addslashes (trim(str_replace("\r\n"," ",$_POST[description])))."'";
```